# Set Background of button based on Content or CustomDP value

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a button whose Content property keeps changing based on certain conditions which are set from the ViewModel. Essentially it gets set a value from 0 to 1000.

I also have another custom DP property on the same button whose value can be set to a certain enum.

What I am trying to solve is as follows (and unfortunately have no idea how I should go about it):

If my button content value is 0 - background of the button should be Gray.
If my button content value is 1 - background of the button should be Yellow.
If my button content value is 1 & the Custom DP has a value set (not the default value) - background should change to Red.

If my problem statement was just dealing with setting a background based on the integer set on the content - I could easily use Converters (String to Brush) and set my background. But the last condition which is now setting my background based on custom DP value coming in - have no idea how to solve...

Can somebody please suggest me an approach - sample code to solve such a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <Button Content="0">
        <Button.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Button">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},Path=Content}" Value="0">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gray"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},Path=Content}" Value="1">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger>
                        <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Content}" Value="1"/>
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=YourDP}" Value="YourValue"/>
                        </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                        </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                    </MultiDataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Button.Style>
    </Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use multi-conditions triggers or multi data triggers. See this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.multitrigger.conditions%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.multidatatrigger%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).